# why I can't access a service created using $provide.provider with $injector.get

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```
function configure($provide, $injector) {

    $provide.provider("testservice", function () {
       this.$get = function () {
         this.property = 777;
       };
    });

    var s = $injector.get("testservice");
```

The last line throws this error:

```
Unknown provider: testservice
```

Why so?

Comment: Show what is `$injector`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To access provide in config phase, we need to append 'Provider' to the name of the provider.

```
module.config(function ($provide, $injector) {
    $provide.provider("testservice", function () {
        this.$get = function () {
            this.property = 777;
        };
    });

    var s = $injector.get("testserviceProvider");
    console.log(s)
});
```

Comment: thanks, indeed it worked. I then tried to inject `$provide` into controller during run phase and received the error: `Unknown provider: $provideProvider <- $provide <- someController`. Is it not possible to inject  `$provide` during run phase?

Comment: No. We will not be able to inject $provide in run phase.